# Punctuation with gerunds

Tags: gerunds, punctuation

Can someone please help me locate the punctuation rule for gerunds? I am almost certain a comma should be placed before the gerund "**claiming**" in the sentence below, but I cannot find any grammatical explanation anywhere. Am I confusing gerunds with participles here?

> "For years Chevy and Ford fans have been battling each other claiming
>   that one's loyal company was better than the other."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**claiming** is not a gerund in this sentence: it is a participle, and it heads a participle phrase. The participle phrase modifies "Chevy and Ford fans", which it  doesn't follow immediately, so a comma is required.

Furthermore, **for years** is an adverbial phrase: when you place an adverbial phrase at the start of a sentence, a comma is required.

> For years, Chevy and Ford fans have been battling each other, claiming that one's loyal company was better than the other.

This excellent [article](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) describes the difference between gerunds and participles, and explains the punctuation rules in various situations.